# How to copy the value of std::string to char[] properly?

Tags: c++

When I try to convert

```
char abc[65536]; 
std::string str; //= "abc";
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), abc); // abc = "abcÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ..."
```

When I to copy the value of `str` into `abc`, I'm getting `ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ..` in addition.

How do I fix this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string` has a constructor that accepts `char*`, so:

```
std::string str(abc);
```

edit: oh you changed the question. Your problem is with null termination.

`str` has 3 characters. `copy` copies these 3 characters. This means `abc` is not (yet) null-terminated. So you don't know where the end of the string is.

try

```
abc[str.length()] = 0;
```

to null-terminate it.

I would also recommend dynamically allocating this memory because 1. 64kb on the stack is a lot, and 2. you are setting yourself up for a hard-to-find disaster and/or security holes by making assumptions about a string size.

If you can use `const char *`, then consider just using `str.c_str()` to access the underlying array.

Comment: oh sorry, I've inversed the question!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `std::copy`. Simply call the `c_str()` method on `std::string`.

```
char * cstr = new char [str.length()+1];
std::strcpy (cstr, str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strcpy(abc,str.c_str())`, this will copy the string from `str` to `abc`.